# Как правильно поступить, если у игроков разный пинг?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, ping

Я пишу игровой сервер - MMORPG Fantasy game. И задался вопросом о соединении с клиентом. А именно пинг. Как правильно поступить, если у одного игрока пинг 400 (к примеру) у второго - 40. Мне отключать клиента из-за плохого соединения? Или запускать какие нибудь оптимизированные сервисы?

Comment: 400 чего? За эти 400 попугаев человек физически способен и игра в целом допускает что произойдет несколько активных действий от одного игрока?

Comment: Продвинутые сервера эмулируют процессы на клиенте, чтобы отрисовка не запаздывала ожидая сервер, а потом сервер сверяет данные и корректирует ситуацию. Но проще конечно выкидывать таких на мороз.

Comment: А клиент, у которого плохой пинг никак не должен вредить серверу и самой игре. Код надо писать так, чтобы все клиенты работали исправно. И 400, я бы сказал, это не плохой пинг. В общем, от плохого пинга должен страдать только тот клиент, у которого проблемы со связью. Отключать его надо только если соединение испортилось и не подлежит восстановлению, например потеряны важные данные и невозможно клиента далее привести в порядок.

Comment: Если у вас есть "какие нибудь оптимизированные сервисы" то запускайте их сразу, чего вы ждете? Я с пингом 390 хочу максимально комфортной игры сразу же, а не ждать, пока пинг до 401 вырастет ))

Comment: Этот сервис делают сильную нагрузку и диагностику сети клиента с сервером. Вы становитесь особенным клиентом. Правда временно. Если соединение в течении 10 минут продолжает пинговать высоко - сервис отключается и выкидывает вас с сервера с кодом ошибки 0xF5 (Плохо соединение с интернетом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MMO играть с таким пингом конечно не комфортно, но: есть ряд разных старых сетевых игр, которые с пингом 200 вполне себе не плохо проявляли себя. Тот же wow при отсутсвии альтернативных серверов с данным пингом терпимо игрался.
Если игра не требует активных действий и быстрой реакции на уровне концепта и не представляет из себя ММО-файтинг в пвп в плане: один бьёт - другой блокирует, то можно на стороне клиента формировать что-то вроде потока действий с таймингом, и отправлять его (кстати смотрите в сторону нового протокола QUIC, он может помочь в плане скорости). В итоге на стороне клиента можем видеть анимации и эффекты, а с задержкой от сервера получать подтверждения в виде единиц нанесённого урона или сообщениях по типу: цель слишком далеко, вы оглушены, итд...